# Convert from Rotation Matrix to Fixed-Axis (Extrinsic) zxz Euler Angles

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations, rigid-transformation, orientation

How can an arbitrary rotation matrix

$R = \left(\begin{matrix} R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \\ R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \\ R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33}\end{matrix}\right)$

be decomposed into the equivalent fixed-axis zxz Euler angles ($\theta,\phi,\psi$)?

I understand the decomposition into the equivalent body-axis Euler angles, but I don't follow the decomposition for the fixed-axis situation.

Comment: If you have the body-axis set of angles, then you just need to reverse the sequence of rotations to get the correct angles in the extrinsic axes. Since you're using a set of rotations that uses the same axes backwards or forwards, that should be no problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Didn't realize it was that easy.